# How to make multilanguage C# console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, internationalization, multilingual

I want to create console application in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express that will have support for a few languages: it will show messages in selected language. What is the simpliest and convenient way to make it international-ready?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to use assembly resource files using the project menu then add resources to your file.

To use the language specific resources in your program:

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager mgr = new
    System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyConsoleApp.MyResource",
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()) ;

Console.WriteLine ( mgr.GetString ("resourceName"));

Console.ReadLine ();
```

Comment: Now it loads my system language. How can I change it to check other languages?

Comment: You can set the culture of the current thread by using
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US")
where en-US is the RFC3066 code.

This link has a full tutorial to help
http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/multi-languagesupport/article.php/c5601/

Comment: Also: the method GetString() of ResourceManager is overloaded. The method takes a CultureInfo object as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use satellite assemblies as shown in this MS article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-satellite-assemblies

Comment: Where can I download this sample?

Comment: I'm not sure for VS2010, for some earlier versions the samples used to be included on the installation media for VS or MSDN but I'm not sure if that's the case any more.
The only online link I can find is this one http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=41c68033-775c-4d92-a9c4-2db8e8238f37&DisplayLang=en where you can download an old version of the sample at least

Answer (score 0):

Principally, you want to be using Resource files.
This link should put you on the right path:

http://www.jelovic.com/articles/resources_in_visual_studio.htm

Once you've got resx files for your different languages, the `ResourceManager` class has a `GetString` method that takes a CultureInfo object, so it would return the right translation for the current culture, or the fallback value if there's no resource of that name in the translated resx file.